# Replace numbers below threshold # in numpy array with zeroes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

So I have a very big Numpy array (2560x1920). Its actually from a grayscale picture where every pixel is given a number from 0-1 indicating its brightness.

I'm trying to replace all values below a threshold, say 0.5, with zeroes.
This is probably a simple task but I'm a beginner with Numpy and I've searched around and still can't figure it out.

This is what I've attempted and I know its wrong...

```
for x in np.nditer(Image):
    if x < .5:
        x == 0

plt.imshow(Image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

It just outputs the normal image without changing anything.

Also the array looks something like this (abbreviated obviously):

```
[[ 0.24565263  0.24565263  0.24902149 ...,  0.27528678  0.27265316
   0.27606536]
 [ 0.24565263  0.24565263  0.24902149 ...,  0.27870309  0.27606536
   0.27948296]
 [ 0.24228902  0.24228902  0.24565263 ...,  0.28212482  0.27948296
   0.282906  ]
 ..., 
 [ 0.29706944  0.29706944  0.29706944 ...,  0.17470162  0.17144636
   0.17144636]
 [ 0.29362457  0.29362457  0.29362457 ...,  0.17144636  0.16495056
   0.16170998]
 [ 0.2901852   0.2901852   0.2901852  ...,  0.16819602  0.16170998
   0.15847427]]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is numpy's builtin indexing which can be used for replacing elements. This is can be done as:

```
Image[Image<0.5] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have returned from the future with suggestions.

The above approaches work great for a simple global threshold. 
I'm posting this answer to warn that non-adaptive thresholding, like this, may be too naïve depending on your application.

Without adaptation to an image's average brightness or other qualities, your output won't be consistent if you are analyzing multiple pictures taken in different conditions.

There are much more accurate approaches for this, but they are a tiny bit more complicated. Scikit-Image makes this easy.

One of the most popular approaches is Otsu's (I can't say which is the most accurate for each situation, I haven't researched enough).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method

Scikit-Image has this and a few other algorithms built into their modules.

The answer to the question above, using this approach, is as simple as this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu

thresh = threshold_otsu(Image)
binary = Image > thresh

plt.imshow(Image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

Read an example here:
http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_otsu.html

And about usage here:
http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html?highlight=local%20otsu