# Removing background from galaxy photos using Python

Tags: python, image-processing

Could you give me some hint about how to remove the background from galaxy images using Python? I want to somehow detect the galaxy and remove everything outside of it.

Any chance to do it with `OpenCV` maybe?

All images look like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove background colour from image using Python/PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217384/remove-background-colour-from-image-using-python-pil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Basic idea of this solution is, get the contours of the image after performing `threshold()` and detect the biggest contour among contours.

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("test.jpg", 1)
img = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU,img)
im2, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

if len(contours) != 0:
    #find the biggest area
    c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),1)

cv2.imshow("Result", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**OUTPUTS:**

[image]
  [image]

Comment: Simple and effective. Love it!